# What is the fastest way to sort/filter an object into multiple objects?

Tags: javascript, performance, javascript-objects

I have an object that looks like this that I want to split out and put each property into its relevant class:

```
inputData = {contact__name:"john",othercontact__name:"sue",othercontact2__name:"joe",company__id:"123"}
```

- Each property is composed of the class name + '__' + property name.
- The values are always strings.
- inputData will never have more than a hundred properties

Currently I do something like this, but I feel like this may not be the best or fastest way of going about it.

```
const contact = new Contact(), othercontact = new Contact(), company = new Company(), custom = new Custom();
const sortInputIntoObjects = (_inputData) => {
  let subkey = [];
  const tempObj = {};
  for (key in _inputData) {
    subkey = key.split('__');
    switch (subkey[0]) {
      case 'contact': {    
          contact[subkey[1]] = _inputData[key];
        break;
      }          
      case 'othercontact': {
           othercontact[subkey[1]] = _inputData[key];
        break;
      }
      case 'company': {
          company[subkey[1]] = _inputData[key];
        break;
      }
      default: {     
          custom[subkey[1]] = _inputData[key];
      }
    }
  }
};
```

After the sorting, each object gets sent to its relative API.

Is there a better way of doing this? Perhaps a map/reduce/filter or is this best as is?

NOTE: this is for Zapier code and can only be ES8 on V8 and cannot use external libraries.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing in `case 'othercontact':`. It won't match `othercontact2`, so why are you trying to extract the number from the end? `othercontact2` will be processed by the `default:` case.

Comment: I don't think `parseInt()` ever returns `null`. If the number can't be parsed, it returns `NaN`, not `null`.

Comment: Why do you set `keyNum = -1` when it's not null? Did you mean `keyNum -= 1`?

Comment: I don't think this code works at all, so we can't help with a better way to do it. And if it does work as you intend, [codereview.se] is the place to ask for help improving it.

Comment: It would help if you showed what the intended result should be.

Comment: @Barmar, terribly sorry about the confusing pieces of code, I should have left that part out. I adjusted my code in the post to reflect what I am doing better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No point in pre-initialising `subkey` and `tempObj`, and the `switch`/`case` can be simplified using a lookup object (or `Map`):

```
function sortInputIntoObjects(inputData) {
  const contact = new Contact(),
        othercontact = new Contact(),
        company = new Company(),
        custom = new Custom();
  const objects = {contact, othercontact, company};
  for (const key in inputData) {
    const subkey = key.split('__');
    const object = objects[subkey[0]] ?? custom;
    object[subkey[1]] = _inputData[key];
  }
}
```

This may or may not be faster, but it's certainly simpler.